# Return enum value or use boolean getters

Tags: java, oop, enums, getter

I have a question that might be a matter of pure taste, however I just like to get some opinions from different angles to become more clear about this.

A class reads and writes status values from and into a database. There are currently 5 status values, they might become a few more. For brevity, I only use 3 status values in the example. Also, though this is Java code, the concept can be transferred to other languages as well.

```
class Status {
  private enum Value { FAILED, FINISHED, RUNNING }

  // getters (read from db)
  // ...
  // setters (write into db)
  // ...
}
```

I can't decide whether I should use generic getters and setters like

```
Value get()

void set(Value value)
```

or if I should create specific getters and setters with more semantics like

```
boolean isRunning()
boolean hasFailed()
boolean hasFinished()  // could also be named isFinished()...

void setFailed()
void setFinished()
void setRunning()
```

The component is not performance-critical, still the obvious drawback of the semantic getters is that you need multiple database reads for `if-else if` statements and `switch` cannot be used. On the other hand, it hides the internal details of the implementation from the consumer and there is no need to work with the enum values outside this class:

```
if (status.get() == Status.Value.RUNNING) { ... }
```

vs.

```
if (status.isRunning()) { ... }
```

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a little too opinion-dependent. However, if your number of statuses is finite and small enough, **and** if they are mutually exclusive (i.e. can't be running and failed at the same time, etc.), then you can easily provide boolean getter/setter pairs whose implementation will change the current `Value` status internally.

Comment: @Mena potential mutual dependencies are a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If clients have to write multiple times comparisons such as :

```
if (status.get() == Status.Value.RUNNING) { ... }
```

You provide probably a too much fine grained API for the enum field containing in the `Status` class.
It will force each client to have duplicate code or otherwise create their own util methods such as `boolean isRunning(Status status){return status.get() == Status.Value.RUNNING}`.

It is not a good idea for two reasons :

- the boiler plate code has to be in the internal/implementation of the API, not in the client side.
- a method has to be located in the class that suits best to hold it. In this case, this is `Status`. Don't constraint clients classes to take the  responsibility of this method.

Note that you should not provide both : Value getter/setter + specific methods for them. It could be misleading.

Comment: I actually thought of having specific + generic getters and only specific setters. This way, the multiple db accesses could be avoided while still providing semantic methods for most easy cases where only one call is needed. However, I agree that it generally might be confusing to have multiple ways to retrieve the same information.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mena that this is opinion based, I would prefer using isRunning, hasFailed etc. 
Because names give more meaning and is much shorter and more understandable.

As you wrote:

```
if (status.get() == Status.Value.RUNNING) { ... }

if (status.isRunning()) { ... }
```

The second option is much shorter and gives better overall sense of what is happening, but again this is more of personal thing.

Also you could consider having more functional approach, something similar to Optional, for example `ifFailed(Consumer<Throwable>)`.